# Select and display by a value of a number

Tags: mysql

I want to select from my database and to display each value by a value of a number, example:

I have in database this:

```
Peter  3.80
Maria  5.67
John   2.52
Robert 1.53
```

I want to display this values but I want to display by example Maria show more times than Robert because she have value of number 5.67 and Robert have 1.53

Output must be Names like Maria, John...

At every refresh show me one name but I need frequency with value number high

Comment: show us, what you have done so far (php code or s.th. like that)

Comment: @trpx I don't write anything because i don't have any idea how!

Comment: then please edit your question and show us, how the output should look like.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for **order by**. Just use order by col_name, here you may wanna add **desc** for descending order

Comment: No no, Maria have number 5.67 that need have high rate of displaying Robert have 1.53 that need low rate of displaying

Comment: Can you please give the order which you like to display? Or you just need the highest count?

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching for sorting the name by the value of number ?

You can try use

```
SELECT name 
FROM your table name 
ORDER BY your column name DESC;
```

You can see reference here to for this [Mysql Sort](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html)